# File Not Saved Error, converting excel sheet to PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have spent quite a bit looking for answer on the web, and maybe im just dumb?

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
FName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & "\" & IRN & Space(1) & OLDA & Space(1) & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & Space(1) & ".pdf"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: (a) Does the variable `FName` contain a valid filename after it is set?  (For instance, if the variables `IRN` and `OLDA` contained a colon, the name created would not be a valid filename and the save would not work.)  (b) Is it saving to a file that already exists and is currently open?

Comment: Ah I guess i was too tired (or dumb) to notice OLDA needed to be formatted to the correct date format as well. Post as answer and receive feedback deserved

Comment: It's always the simple things that take the longest to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common reasons that would cause it to be unable to save the file.

1. The filename is invalid - this could occur in your case if either
   of `IRN` or `OLDA` contained characters which are invalid in a file
   name, such as a colon.
2. The file that is to be saved already exists but is open.  This
   would lock the file and prevent it being written over.